# watchOS2 and iOS8 connectivity - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

For **watchOS1** there were several limited, but efficient methods available for sharing data between the watch and the phone - like `openParentApp`, `AppGroups` and `NSUserDefaults`.

With the release of **watchOS2** and the **WatchConnectivity** framework - `openParentApp`  method was deprecated, `AppGroups` and `NSUserDefaults` were limited to read-only functionality. Important to note here that WatchConnectivity is supported only by **iOS9** devices.

But somehow i see apps on the AppStore claiming to be optimised for **watchOS2** while 
having an **iOS8** as deployment target.

Am i missing something?
Are there any other methods available for sharing data sufficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some user may not have Apple Watch and they may using iOS8.
To support them, You can set each deployment target version per each build target.

Likes these example targets in a project:

- iOS App (target: iOS 8.x, You must set `WatchConnectivity` framework as optional)
- watchOS 2 App (target: iOS 9.x & watchOS 2) -> iOS8 User can't install watch app.
- watchOS 2 App Exntension (target: iOS 9.x & watchOS 2)

In the iOS App Codes, You can check `WatchConnectivity` availability with below codes:

```
NSClassFromString(@"WCSession") != nil;
```

As far as I know, You can also provides watchOS 1 App in sametime, But I did not test it. It can't be tested with simulator and I don't have other apple watch that have watchOS1.

Comment: WCSession is not present in WatchOS1

Comment: @サンディープ Yes, everybody knows that, So I said that you have to set link `WatchConnectivity` as optional and check it in runtime. Linking framework and deployment target are not tied.